# Box2DLights - the center of sprites are always 100% unlit (black) unless Xray is on

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, lighting

I'm using a ConeLight at 180 degrees, with this setup:
`pl = new ConeLight(rayHandler, 256, new Color(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1f), 280f, 400 - x, 300 - y, 0, 180);`
And the object I'm casting a shadow on (with?) is set up like so:

```
sprite = new Sprite(new Texture(imgP));

BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
bodyDef.position.set(x - 392.5f, y - 292.5f);

body = Main.world.createBody(bodyDef);

PolygonShape pushBlock = new PolygonShape();

pushBlock.setAsBox(((float) w / 2), ((float) h / 2));

FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
fixtureDef.shape = pushBlock;
fixtureDef.density = 0.5f; 
fixtureDef.friction = 0.8f;
fixtureDef.restitution = 0f;

Fixture fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);

body.setUserData(sprite);
body.setGravityScale(0);
body.setFixedRotation(true);
body.setLinearDamping(40f);

pushBlock.dispose();
```

The problem is that the light creates the shadows in a sort of glob form in the center of the square (not casting nicely around the corners as I've seen in others' projects), also leaving nearly the whole sprite black. I require the ambient colour to be black, and also require shadows, so Xray is out. I've messed around with filters but haven't been able to achieve what I want - **being able to cast shadows without overshadowing the sprite.**
Is it possible? How might I do this, if possible?

Edit: I took a screenshot.[image: The screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs to be done when you create the Box2DLight's Light object.

You can fix this by setting the [setSoftnessLength(float)](https://github.com/libgdx/box2dlights/blob/master/src/box2dLight/Light.java#L298) on the Light object.

For example:

```
m_Light = new ConeLight(...);
m_Light.setSoftnessLength(1.5f);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't vote your answer up yet.